# Tengo muchisimos paquetes en mi venv

Tags: python, django, consola, pip, packages

Cuando realizo un "pip freeze" en la consola de mi proyecto de Django me aparecen muchisimos paquetes que instale para otros proyectos que realice. Lo cual es muy raro porque tengo mi entorno virtual activado. Alguien sabe porque sucede eso

Comment: Muchas veces al instalar un paquete con pip este especifica otro montón de paquetes de los que depende para poder funcionar, por lo que pip los instala todos también. Por eso no es raro que, aún si has usado pip para instalar solo un par de cosas, cuando hagas pip freeze te salen muchísimas cosas más. De todas formas no es posible saber con la información que aportas si lo que te sale en pip freeze es "normal", o puede ser síntoma de algún otro problema, pero me inclino a pensar que es "normal".

Comment: Tus anteriores proyectos  también estaban en entornos virtuales? Prueba con el parámetro -l para evitar los paquetes globales